# Remove errors when mounted vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i'm trying to make the border-color not turn red each time the page is mounted , i only want the border to turn red each time i click on the submit button

this is my code

```
 <select
              
                class="form-control padding-10 padding-bottom-0"
                v-model="obj.questionId"
                :class="{
                  'form-error-outline':

                    v$.answerList.$each.$response.$errors[index].questionId
                      .length > 0,
                }"
                >
                <option
                  value
                  selected
                  disabled
                  hidden
                >
                  Select a question
                </option>
              </select>
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { helpers, required, sameAs } from "@vuelidate/validators";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      v$: useVuelidate()
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      answerList: [
        {
          questionId: "",
          answer: ""
        },
        {
          questionId: "",
          answer: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      answerList: {
        $each: helpers.forEach({
          questionId: { required },
          answer: { required }
        })
      }
    };
  },
 
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.v$.$touch();

      if (this.v$.$invalid) {
        return;
      }

      
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

the border-color shows red on default, how can i make the border turn red only after clicking submit

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think to do this is, within your data you can have a boolean(lets call it applyborder) and default it to false. and then apply a conditional class like this

```
<div :class="applyborder ? 'border-red' : ''">
...
</div>
```

Change the value of applyborder to true when submit is clicked.